# How do I escape a semicolon (;) character for an Azure DevOps SSH task?

Tags: azure-devops, escaping, special-characters

I am trying to run a command like:

```
java -jar pathToJar/jarFile.jar "connectionstring=jdbc:impala:server:port;param1=value1"
```

I am running it via an [Azure DevOps SSH task](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821892). The problem with this is that the semicolon character (`;`) is a special character (command separator). I've tried escaping with `\` but that doesn't help.

With no escaping I see the following command has been run:

```
java -jar pathToJar/jarFile.jar "connectionstring=jdbc:impala:server:port
```

The `;param1=value1` suffix is missing.

Comment: The `;` is not a special character in the code you've posted. Please include a MCVE showing what you mean.

Comment: @thatotherguy I just tested again with that input and the effect is as I said. I am not running this directly from the shell, but via a release pipeline script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SshV0/ssh.ts) on GitHub, I'm assuming that you have 'Commands' selected as the run option. By default it splits the command on ; or line break. In this case you need to switch the option to 'inline' or put it in a script file and run it that way.

[image: SSH Task Commands Option]

Use 'inline' if you are going to have a single command that contains a semi-colon

[image]